# QWidgetAction:hover in QMenuBar isn't working and doesn't want to hover

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qwidgetaction

I am using class `QMainWindow`, as hovering doesn't want to work by any way.

Code below: -

```
#First imports
import PyQt5, sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QFileDialog, QMdiSubWindow, QMdiArea, QToolBar, QAction, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QMenuBar, QWidgetAction, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextOption, QFont, QPixmap, QImage, QIcon

class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
    
#The code below is inside QMainWindow class and win = the class UI(QMainWindow) then win.show()

        self.setStyleSheet("""

        QMenuBar {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            border: 3px solid silver;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 23px;
        }

        QMenuBar::item {
            background-color: white;
            border: 2px solid silver;
        }

        QMenuBar::item::selected {
            background-color: grey;
        }
        
        QLabel:hover { 
            background-color: grey;
        }

/*note that this is a tag: I tried both QLabel and QWidgetAction :hover method and its not working*/
        
        """)

        self.Menu = QMenuBar(self)
        self.Menu.resize(self.width(), 40)
        self.Menu.move(0, 0)
        
        self.File = self.Menu.addMenu('File')
        
        self.FileNew = QWidgetAction(self.File)
        self.New = QLabel("New")

        self.New.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.New.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.New.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid silver; "
                       "background-color: white; color: black; "
                       "padding: 4 4 4 4px")
        self.FileNew.setDefaultWidget(self.New)

        self.File.addAction(self.FileNew)

def Start1():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = UI()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()

Start1()
```

I searched in many threads and docs about `:hover` method and tried it but it didn't work for me. And when I hover with my mouse on the `QWidgetAction` it stills frozen.

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre], as the code indicated in your title (assuming you actually use that syntax) seems quite wrong.

Comment: What all I need is to make the :hover method for the QWidgetAction in the QMenuBar "File", Please if you can provide it to me. @musicamante

Comment: I did @musicamante

Comment: Sorry but no, you didn't, that code alone is insufficient to understand where the problem actually is. Please read the link above and follow its directions carefully, we need a code that we can eventually copy, paste and run without substantial modifications, so that we can *reproduce* your issue and eventually understand what causes it.

Comment: I did again the idea is I want example of how to make the :hover method for a QWidgetAction inside a QMenu in the QMenuBar in which once I hover over the QWidgetAction, it changes its background-color and color. (In setStyleSheet method)

Comment: @musicamante QLabel or QWidgetAction then :hover at the tag # in QLabel:hover { 
            background-color: grey;
        }
the problem is there :hover doesnt wanna work with both
#I tried both QLabel and QWidgetAction

Comment: We already know what you want, but you're still *NOT* providing what requested: we need code that we can *copy, paste and run without substantial modifications*. Now, copy *exactly* the code above from your question, paste it into a new Python file, and try to execute it: does it run? No, and that's what we have from you right now: an incomplete and **not reproducible** code. So, for one last time, read the link in my first comment, and take your time to create a *valid* MRE: note that we do **not** need your full code, but a minimal code that is able to reproduce your issue, meaning that »

Comment: » you'll probably need to create a new script from scratch, conceptually based on your current code, but without anything that is not relevant to your problem. If you're able to run *and* reproduce the issue, then you'll probably got a proper MRE. We need such codes, because insufficient examples result in wild guesses and assumptions (that are rarely correct): the stylesheet you gave us *should* do what you need (except for the `#` comment, which is a CSS/QSS syntax error), so you're probably doing something wrong somewhere else, and we cannot tell you what it is until you provide what asked.

Comment: Here edited the code copy and paste it then run it. @musicamante

Comment: I forgot that we use /*...*/ for css and I used # (which is python comment) as css comment 

Comment: Ok, that's better, but the issue is still not reproducible: you never add the action to the menu, so the label is never shown at all (which is a problem that comes way before than the hovering issue). I'm going on a hunch and *assume* that you actually do that in your original code, but, please, for future reference, ensure that the *reproducibility* of your examples refers not only to the ability to run the code, but to reproduce *the issue*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of issues in your code, affecting the problem to different levels, but the most important one is that you are practically overwriting the style sheet for the label, completely ignoring the style sheets that could be inherited by the parent.

<sup>Your current code also doesn't add the action to the menu, I'm going to assume that you just forgot it, but that's quite important nonetheless.</sup>

When setting style sheets, it's almost always necessary to use property selectors (even in "final widgets" that do not contain further children), especially if pseudo states like `:hover` may be inherited.

The following rule is applied on the window:

```css
        QLabel:hover { 
            background-color: grey;
        }
```

But then, since you're using generic properties in the label style sheet, they will override any previously set rule. Consider the original code:

```py
        self.New.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid silver; "
                       "background-color: white; color: black; "
                       "padding: 4 4 4 4px")
```

Which is almost identical to this:

```py
        self.New.setStyleSheet("""
            * { 
                border: 2px solid silver; 
                background-color: white; color: black; 
                padding: 4 4 4 4px;
            }
        """)
```

The wildcard selector applies the properties to any widget in any state, including the `:hover` one.

A more appropriate solution could be to use the correct selector, which sets the default properties for any state, but also specify the case that *negates* the hover state:

```py
        self.New.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel { 
                border: 2px solid silver; 
                color: black; 
                padding: 4 4 4 4px;
            }
            QLabel:!hover {
                background-color: white;
            }
        """)
```

In reality, both the style sheets (window and label) should probably be merged, and using more correct selectors:

```py
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            /* ...QMenuBar as above */

            QMenu > QLabel { 
                border: 2px solid silver; 
                color: black; 
                padding: 4 4 4 4px;
                background-color: white;
            }

            QMenu > QLabel:hover { 
                background-color: grey;
            }
```

I strongly recommend you to read the whole QSS documentation, especially the [syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html), [reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) and [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html) pages (but not excluding the others). In any case, the rule of thumb is that you should always consider selector types, and generic properties should only be used if you are *completely* sure of what you are doing.

As said, there are other relevant issues:

- the menu bar is just added as a child of the window and never set as an *actual* menubar; if you need a custom menu bar, you must *always* properly set it by using [`setMenuBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setMenuBar); if you are not using a QMainWindow, a similar function is also provided for all QLayout classes;
- QMainWindow already provides a menu bar that can be automatically created (see [`menuBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#menuBar) if none already exists), so, unless you really need to use a custom subclass, you should use that instead;
- as said, you never add the action to the menu; even if you did it in your real code, remember that you must also do that *after* calling `setDefaultWidget()`, otherwise the widget would not be shown;
- capitalized names are normally reserved to class and constant names (see the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008), but it's also convention in most programming languages), and you should avoid to use that style for variables and attributes, as it makes code less readable;

Comment: I real forgot .addAction() method, thanks for your time it worked.